# Evaluating an expression in maple

Tags: numerical, maple

I have a complicated expression in **maple** which depends on four real parameters, say `a,b,c,d`. Let us call this expression `f(a,b,c,d)`. This expression consists of derivatives, definite and indefinite integrals of hyperbolic functions. By indefinite integral I mean expressions like `Int(g(x),x)`. The expression `f` is to big for maple to write out, and I would therefore like to evaluate it numerically for different values of `a,b,c and d`. I tried doing `evalf(value(f(a1,b1,c1,d1))`, but this never terminates in maple, which I guess means that maple first tries to simplify f algebraically and then plugs in the real values `a1,b1,c1, and d1.`

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

After the symbolic manipulation Maple will return an expression in terms of other variables for example:

```
diff(x^2 + 2, x);  will return "2 x"
```

now if you write `evalf(%)`, it will not be able to evaluate to any numerical value because it does not know the value of `x`. Therefore you have to first use `subs()` function to substitute the value of `x` where you want to evaluate the resulting expression.

Thus, in your case it will be `subs([x=2, y=5], f(a, b, c, d))` assuming that the evaluated expression has variables `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **value** command. It tries to evaluate your integrals symbolically, which is probably impossible. Just use **evalf**.

Comment: I tried doing this, but then the integrals in my expression are not calculated.

Comment: It may be possible to numerically evaluate the integrals in your expression by reducing the requested accuracy. You do this with the **digits** and **epsilon** parameters to **Int**.